# Fitting a curve to some segment of another curve

Tags: algorithm, curve-fitting

Maybe I should ask this in Mathoverflow but here it goes:

I have 2 data sets (sets of x and y coordinates) with different number of elements. I have to find the best match between them by stretching one of the data sets (multiplying all x with a factor of **m** and all y with a factor of **n**) and moving it around (adding **p** and **q** to all x and y respectively).

Basically these 2 sets represent different curves and i have to fit curve B (which has less elements) to some segment of curve A (which has many more elements).

How can I find the values **m**, **n**, **p**, and **q** for the closest match?

Answers can be pseudo code, C, Java or Python. Thanks.

Comment: What's your criteria for a good/close match? A trivial solution would be to move all the points of B on the first point of A: multiply x and y by `m = n = 0` and then add the first data point from A as offset p,q. Or you can make a horizontal line, by multiply only Y by `m = 0` and search for the flattest segment in A.

Comment: Great response. Thanks. (m > 0 && n > 0) and for all x of B | max(x of A) > m*x of B > min(x of A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is a solution for finding values m, n, p and q when after transforming the first curve it matches exactly with a part of the second curve:

Basically, we have to solve the following matrix equation:

```
[m n][x y]' + [p q]' = [X Y]' ...... (1)
```

where [x y]' and [X Y]' are the coordinates of first and second curves respectively. Let's assume first curve has total l number of coordinates and second curve has total h number of coordinates.

```
(1) implies, 
[mx+p ny+1]' = [X Y]'
```

i.e we have to solve:

```
mx_1+p = X_k, mx_2+p = X_{k+1}, ..., mx_l+p = X_{k+l-1}
ny_1+q = Y_k, ny_2+q = Y_{k+1}, ..., ny_l+q = Y_{k+l-1}

where k+l-1 <= h-l
```

We can solve it in the following naive way:

```
for (i=1 to h-l){
    (m,p) = SOLVE(x1, X_i, x2, X_{i+1})// 2 unknowns, 2 equations
    (n,q) = SOLVE(y1, Y_i, y2, Y_{i+1})// 2 unknowns, 2 equations
    for (j=3 to l){
        if(m*x[j]+p != m*X[i+2]+p)break;//value of m, p found from 1st 2 doesn't work for rest
        if(n*y[j]+q != n*Y[i+2]+q)break;//value of n, q found from 1st 2 doesn't work for rest
    }
    if(j==l){//match found
        return i;//returns the smallest index of 2nd curves' coordinates where we found a match
    }
 }
 return -1;//no match found
```

I am not sure if there can be an optimized version of this.